# How to set a user agent and use a proxy?

Tags: node-webkit

The documents read as follows:

> user-agent
>
> since v0.3.7
>
> (string) Override the User-Agent header in HTTP requests made from the application. 
>   The following placeholders are available:
>
> %name: replaced by the name field in the manifest.
>      %ver: replaced by the version field in the manifest, if available.
>      %nwver: replaced by the version of node-webkit.
>      %webkit_ver: replaced by the version of WebKit engine.
>      %osinfo: replaced by the OS and CPU information you would see in browser's user agent string.

Can someone give me an example of how this implemented? eg. Current user agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 ...
```

Say I want to make it:

```
Chrome/5.0 (Windows NT) Chrome/35.0.1916 ...
```

Also, I'd like to use a proxy... is that possible within node-webkit?

Answer (score 0):

User-Agent: In the package.json:

```
"name":"TheNameOfTheApp",
"version":"0.0.1",
"private":true,
"main":"index.html",
"dependencies":{
   "express":"latest",
   ...
}
"window": {
    "title": "MyApp",
    "toolbar": true,
    "frame": true,
    "position": "center",
    "fullscreen": false,
    "resizable": true,
    "width": 1000,
    "height": 600,
    "min_width": 600,
    "min_height": 400
},
"user-agent":"%name NodeWebKit", //-> "TheNameOfTheApp NodeWebKit"
"node-remote": "<local>"
```